# Question About Casorati-Weierstrass Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

I am learning complex analysis and I just learned Casorati-Weierstrass Theorem. The theorem says that if $f$ is holomophic in $U-\{z_0\}$ where $U$ is open, and $f$ has an essential singularity at $z_0$, then for any neighborhood $V$ of $z_0$, if $V \subset U$, we have $f(V-\{z_0\})$ being dense in complex plane.

I am confused with this theorem because of the follow example:

Let $f(z) = 1/z$, then $f$ is holomorphic in $D_r(0) - \{0\} = D$, wher $D_r(0) = \{z: |z| < r\}$, and has essential singularity at $z_0 = 0$

By the theorem we have $f(D)$ being dense in $\mathbb{C}$

However for any $z \in D$, we have $|z| < r$, thus $|1/z| > r$

Let $\epsilon = \frac{r}{2}$, then $D_\epsilon(0) \cap f(D) = \emptyset$, and $f(D)$ must not be dense in $\mathbb{C}$

I am wondering where I was wrong?

Comment: $\frac 1 z$ does not have an essntial singularity at $0$. It has a  simple pole at $0$.

Comment: What does have an essential singularity at $0$ is $e^{1/z}$, for example. And it's Casorati, with an "s".

Comment: Look at the definition of an essential singularity: The Laurent series has infinitely many negative powers (z-z0)^-n.